# How do we find the maximum value of Column 3 from a range of values of Column 1?

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have this dataset on an Ubuntu machine:

```
37.500  0.0000  0.005605
37.750  0.0000  -0.027858
38.000  0.0000  -0.060678
38.250  0.0000  -0.088557
38.500  0.0000  -0.109210
38.750  0.0000  -0.122482
39.000  0.0000  -0.129770
39.250  0.0000  -0.133190
39.500  0.0000  -0.134538
39.750  0.0000  -0.134015
40.000  0.0000  -0.129660
40.250  0.0000  -0.117858
40.500  0.0000  -0.094709
40.750  0.0000  -0.057622
41.000  0.0000  -0.006853
```

And I need to find the maximum value of Column 3 which lies between 38 and 40 in Column 1.

This is a sample dataset only.

Comment: Why does your title say "Column 2" when all the values in column 2 are zero?

Answer (score 6):

```
awk '$1 >= 38 && $1 <= 40 && $3 > max {max = $3; out = $0};
     END {print out}' input.txt
```

Note: there is NO positive value for $3 where 38 <= $1 <= 40.  That's why the output is a blank line. (Why? because `max` defaults to 0, and none of the negative values are higher than that).

If you want the highest value, whether positive or negative, then initialise `max` to a value smaller than the smallest possible value in $3.  e.g. `-9999`:

```
$ awk -v max=-9999 '$1 >= 38 && $1 <= 40 && $3 > max {max = $3; out = $0};
                    END {print out}' input.txt 
38.000  0.0000  -0.060678
```

or, using a `BEGIN` block rather than `-v`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {max=-9999};
       $1 >= 38 && $1 <= 40 && $3 > max {max = $3; out = $0};
       END {print out}' input.txt 
38.000  0.0000  -0.060678
```

or with perl, testing if $max is undefined rather than initialising it to an unlikely value:

```
$ perl -lane  '
  if ($F[0] >= 38 && $F[0] <= 40 && (!defined($max) || $F[2] > $max)) {
    $max = $F[2]; 
    $out = $_;
  };
  END { print $out }'  input.txt 
38.000  0.0000  -0.060678
```

Comment: You can use `-v max=-inf` to initialize, at least with GNU `awk`. It doesn't seem to work with `mawk`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what change has to be made to display the entire row with the maximum value and not just the maximum value?

Comment: @AKASHNAIR I updated the answer to print the entire row.

Comment: @AKASHNAIR If you need to change the question, then please remember to update the text in your question.  As it stands right now, the task is to find the maximum value, not the whole row.

Answer (score 3):

One solution in the Unix spirit of "one tool for one task" could be to filter the lines with `awk`, but then sort with `sort`:

```
awk '$1>=38 && $1<=40' test.txt  | sort -n -k 3 -r | head -n 1
```

Specifically here I use `-n` to sort numerically, `-k3` to use the third column, `-r` to reverse (start with the largest value), and `head -n 1` to show one line. The benefit is that it's super easy to extend to top 3 values, the smallest value, etc.

Comment: Nice, sensible approach!

Answer (score 1):

`sort` -> `sed` solution.

Keep placing matching lines in the hold buffer (`/^(3[89]|40\.000)/h`), and then finally swap hold+pattern buffers (`$x`), and print pattern buffer (`$p`).

```
$ sort -rk 3n test.txt |sed -nE '/^(3[89]|40\.000)/h;$x;$p'
38.000  0.0000  -0.060678
$
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk '
    (38 <= $1) && ($1 <= 40) && ((max == "") || ($3 > max)) {
        max=$3; line=$0
    }
    END { if (max!="") print line }
' file
38.000  0.0000  -0.060678
```

Apart from that being concise, robust, portable, and efficient, there are 3 main rules of thumb being implemented above:

1. Always write range tests with the value you want to test (`$1` in this case) in the middle of the boundaries (`38` and `40` in this case) so it's clear at a glance what the code does so in the above we write `(38 <= $1) && ($1 <= 40)` to clearly show we want cases where `$1` lies between `38` and `40` instead of writing `($1 >= 38) && (40 >= $1)` or `($1 >= 38) && ($1 <= 40)` or any other combination where you have to put a bit more thought into what that means.
2. Never use a specific initial value for min or max calculations, always init min or max to the first input value read. The above tests `max == ""` when setting `max` instead to ensure it'll work no matter what the input contains by simply initializing `max` to the first value read instead of initializing it to some arbitrary value that you **hope** will be less than all the input values.
3. We test `max!=""` before printing `line` in the `END` section
   above to ensure we don't get a blank line printed if/when none of
   the `$1` values lie within the target range.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
~$ raku -e 'lines.map(*.words).grep(38 < *.[0] < 40).map(*.[2].Num).max.say;'  file
```

OR (expanded version):

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.words; @a.=grep(38 < *.[0] < 40); @a.map(*.[2].Num).max.say;'  file
```

The code above returns the single (max) value: `-0.088557` based upon the stated Column_1 criteria. Briefly, `lines` are read in, broken on whitespace separated `words`, `grep`ped to find 1st_column values (zero-indexed = `.[0]`) between 38 and 40, then the `max` value is pulled out of `Num`ified values in the 3rd_column (zero-indexed = `.[2]`).

*[Note for interested readers: when I change the Column_1 criteria to return zero rows, the code above tells me the `max` Column_3 value obtained is `-Inf`].*

Reading the comments, it appears that the OP also desires to know how to return the entire row containing the value above. The following code accomplishes that task:

```bash
~$ raku -e 'my @a = lines>>.words; @a.=grep(38 < *.[0] < 40); put max(@a, :by(*.[2].Num));'  file
38.250 0.0000 -0.088557
```

Finally, readers might notice that the Column_3 value obtained herein differs from other posted Answers. This is because the Raku code used takes the OP quite literally when the request is for Column_1 values *between* 38 and 40 (i.e. greater that 38 and less than 40). Rest assured, changing the `grep` statements above to use `<=` instead of `<` gives a Column_3 value of `-0.060678` (same as other Answers).

---

Sample Input:

```
37.500  0.0000  0.005605
37.750  0.0000  -0.027858
38.000  0.0000  -0.060678
38.250  0.0000  -0.088557
38.500  0.0000  -0.109210
38.750  0.0000  -0.122482
39.000  0.0000  -0.129770
39.250  0.0000  -0.133190
39.500  0.0000  -0.134538
39.750  0.0000  -0.134015
40.000  0.0000  -0.129660
40.250  0.0000  -0.117858
40.500  0.0000  -0.094709
40.750  0.0000  -0.057622
41.000  0.0000  -0.006853
```

https://raku.org